# Request for publicly available datasets for linear system identification practice

Tags: system-identification, data-request

Apologies if the question is not fit properly here.

**Goal:** I have a system identification project where I need a dataset to construct a dynamic model and perform correlation and/or predictions. The methods are linear (AR,ARX,ARMAX,ARMA,Kalman,nonparametric methods) because I have not learned nonlinear methods in my course.

**Question**: I wish to ask if there are available datasets (downloadable as csv files) that are uploaded by users or authors of articles in the field of:

- **Environmental Modelling**: For instance, creating a time-series forecast model for temperature vs forest fire using AR/ARMAX...
- **Biomedical Modelling**: For instance, creating an ARX model for blood pressure flow...

**Issue**: I have scanned the entire web searching for datasets to construct system id models but the issues I am facing are:

1. Most articles use Nonlinear methods for cited datasets (such as neural networks).
2. Most of the articles that use linear methods are in the early 2000s and the datasets they cite are no where to be found.
3. Most datasets where system ID is used are in a domain (civil/mechanical/chemical engineering) different than mine which is in environmental modelling or biomedical modelling.

Therefore I would kindly ask for your help in referencing me to any dataset that could meet the two requirements above.

Comment: Do you need a reference of the actual system or just data?

Comment: I would like reference for the data even if no literature involved in that data exist. As long as linear system ID works. @Royi

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by ID. I meant do you need data or data + labels (The system which generated it)?

Comment: Oh, I would prefer data+labels in this case @Royi

Comment: Then I'd suggest building your own data set.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. A dataset isn't tied to any model used to process it. If others only used nonlinear methods on dataset X, doesn't mean you can't use linear.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I understand your reasoning but I did try to test a 4th order ARX model on a weather data to predict concentration of ground level ozone, the data was preprocessed and the best fit was around 40% when I read the literature they constructed a two stage Bayesian model.

Comment: Yes, that's because nonlinear methods are superior. I don't know of any linear method that performs well on raw general real-world data. At the very least one would apply a nonlinear preprocessing step, and only then a linear forecasting/classifying step. To create a dataset that works well with linear data, as your question seems to suggest, would be to "cheat".

Comment: At this point, I am in need of any dataset (even if its a simulation dataset) that I could perform  linear system id  @OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: Right, sure. I recommend asking on other SE networks (cross-validated, data science), and on reddit (r/MachineLearning and related) - DSP has a fairly narrow audience, but maybe someone will look for this rather large bounty.

Comment: Idea: pick only samples on which linear methods work well? It's what others would have to do anyway, for such a dataset to exist. Aim for 90%, and explain why linear methods work there and not for the other 10%.

Comment: I think your choice of underlying phenomena makes it hard to get anywhere near 90%.  But EEG data might be susceptible; those without stimulus response experiments (?) .  In theory, what are called "brain waves" should be able to be picked out; the rhythms neuroscientists talk about.  Personally I am more inclined to Wavelets but the ARMA, etc… should be able to point to typical rhythms.  For instance, yearly cycles come out of weather data; but not at explaining 90% :)

Comment: I meant to link: https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/fam2data/publicly_available_EEG_data.html  
Maybe I should get my brain scanned :)

Comment: I've formalized my comments into an answer so they bounty's not wasted, though hopefully someone can offer something better.

Comment: @SPARSE If you ever post an answer, ping me and I'll refund 100. (Though, don't expect this in general with bounties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such datasets either don't exist, or cheat. If linear methods could achieve 90% on real world forecasting tasks, we'd need not sink billions into neural nets and the like.

An option is to create such a dataset yourself, by picking samples such that 90% is achieved - it's what others would have to do anyway. Then, try to explain why the linear methods work there but not on the other 10%. Another option is to apply a nonlinear (but interpretable) preprocessing step ("feature extraction") then apply linear methods.

Fundamentally, most real-world structures aren't *linearly separable*. Nonlinearities enable such separation, and hence classification and regression. Example - nonlinear projection into a higher dimension, enabling linear separation (with a hyperplane):

[image]